# Alt text for Excel Charts - Can I add variables in the description to auto-update the alt text?

Tags: excel, charts, accessibility, screen-readers, vba

Can I add variables to alt text of Excel charts, so that the description updates as the chart updates?

**Why?**
I need to make Excel charts that are accessible for screen readers (used by people with visual impairments). This means adding alt text to charts which will provide a description of the chart's content.

The charts are linked to data tables, and the charts update when those data change, but the alt text does not (e.g., the alt text might say 'Chart showing 56% rise in donations in 2016', but if the data changes, this alt text will need to be manually updated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add the Alt Title and Text using variables with something like:

```
Sheet1.Shapes("Chart 1").Title = "Alt Title" 
Sheet1.Shapes("Chart 1").AlternativeText = "Alt Description"
'You can use a variable here or even a reference to another cell's value
```

Comment: ...and depending on your exact needs, you could execute the above code automatically with the Worksheet Change event, etc.